# How to perform wilcox test in R?

Tags: r

I have this data frame with 4 genes and 3 samples measured in duplicate. 
The TS is the standard.

I want to perform the wilcox test between the sample S1 with TS and S2 with the TS for each protein, but i´m having problems with the for cycle.

```
    MS.rawMV <- read.table("C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/genomic/MS.csv", header=T)
         S1_1     S1_2    S2_1    S2_2     TS_1     TS_2
gene 1    1         1      2        3       5         5 
gene 2    10        10     4        5       9         10   
gene 3    5         6      4        4       5         7
gene 4    9         9      8        7       6         6     


 Samples=list(
  S1=grep("S1_*", colnames(MS.rawMV), value=TRUE),
  S2=grep("S2_*", colnames(MS.rawMV), value=TRUE),
  TS=grep("TS_*", colnames(MS.rawMV), value=TRUE))

sample.names <- names(Samples)
ref.sample <- "TS_"

# Build a data.frame 
GRates <- data.frame(MS.rawMV[Reduce("c", Samples)])

## Statistics: non parametric test using TS as a standart 
for (i in names(Samples)) {
  WILCOXTEST <- wilcox.test(GRates[c(Samples[[i]])],Samples[[ref.sample]])
  pnames <- paste(i,".wilcoxtest",sep="")
  GRates[pnames] <- WILCOXTEST["p.value"]
}

Error in wilcox.test.default(GRates[Samples[[i]]], Samples[[ref.sample[i]]]) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: I do not believe that `wilcox.test` should be able to handle repeated measures type tests. It's also not clear that even if you were only testing S1_1 vs TS_1 that a data situation testing separate genes would be an appropriate application. That seems to be a multinomial problem as well. `wilcox.test` is for comparing a one-way classification of measures of the same property. You have a two-way classification, even if you remove the repeated measures aspect.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data is being treated as a factor.

The easiest fix would be to convert them back to numeric via factor->character->numeric.

try this

```
wilcox.test(
    as.numeric(as.character(GRates[c(Samples[[i]])])),
    as.numeric(as.character(Samples[[ref.sample]]))
)
```

If you try to convert straight to numeric from factor, you'll end up with integers that represent the factor classes instead of the actual values.

Comment: Just fixing the syntactic problem will not a address the semantic statistical problems. Just because one can get the machinery to turn in circles does not mean that the product will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

@DWin's comment is well taken (you have additional structure in your data that is hard to incorporate into a Wilcoxon test).  However, if you want to ignore the distinction between the _1 and _2 columns and run Wilcoxon test on S1 vs TS and S2 vs TS, here's a way to rearrange the data and do it:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
gene S1_1 S1_2    S2_1    S2_2     TS_1     TS_2
1      1    1      2        3       5         5 
2     10   10      4        5       9         10   
3      5    6      4        4       5         7
4      9    9      8        7       6         6",
                  header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
m1 <- melt(dat,id.var="gene")
## break var_num into separate components
m2 <- subset(data.frame(m1,
             colsplit(m1$variable,"_",names=c("var","num"))),
             select=-variable)
## combine treatments with standards
m3 <- merge(subset(m2,var!="TS"),
      subset(m2,var=="TS"),by=c("gene","num"))
## clean up
m4 <- subset(rename(m3,c(value.x="value",var.x="var",value.y="standard")),
             select=-var.y)

## apply Wilcoxon test to each component, save the p value
ddply(m4,"var",
      function(x) with(x,wilcox.test(value,standard))$p.value)
```

Or, if you want to test each replication separately (as in @agstudy's answer), do

```
ddply(m4,c("var","num"),
      function(x) with(x,wilcox.test(value,standard))$p.value)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think , since  `wilcox.test` is not vectorized you need 2 loops. Even I am not sure Of the statistical meaning of this , here how you can do :

```
nn <- colnames(dat)
lapply(1:2,function(x){ 
  col.L <- grep(paste0('S',x,'_*'),nn)
  col.R <- dat[,paste0('TS_',x)]
  lapply(col.L,function(y) 
      wilcox.test(dat[,y],col.R)['p.value'])
})
```

Here I assume `dat` as

```
dat <- read.table(text='S1_1     S1_2    S2_1    S2_2     TS_1     TS_2
gene_1    1         1      2        3       5         5 
gene_2    10        10     4        5       9         10   
gene_3    5         6      4        4       5         7
gene_4    9         9      8        7       6         6',header=TRUE)
```